# Devexpress xaf many to many relationship oid key Name Change

Tags: devexpress, xaf, xpo

I want to set many to many relationship oid key name.
In many to many relationship Oid is created automatically but on database side I want to change oid name to custom name.
For Example;

If I try to create Person and Task many to many relation. Third table attributes in below;

KomutTanim (FK to Makine)
Makine (FK to KomutTanim)
OID (PK, guid)** (I want to set this key name??)**

Tell me how can I do. I added sample code in below

```
    [Association("Relation.KomutListesi_Makine",typeof(KomutTanim),UseAssociationNameAsIntermediateTableName = true),XafDisplayName("Makine Komutları")]
public XPCollection<KomutTanim> Komutlar
{
get
{
return GetCollection<KomutTanim>(nameof(Komutlar));
}
}

[Association("Relation.KomutListesi_Makine", typeof(Makine), UseAssociationNameAsIntermediateTableName = true), XafDisplayName("Makineler")]
public XPCollection<Makine> MasterId
{
get
{
return GetCollection<Makine>(nameof(MasterId));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize XPO metadata or manually create a persistent class for your intermediate table. These approaches are illustrated in the [How to implement a many-to-many relationship with an intermediate table](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/q450710) ticket.

The solution with customizing XPO metadata uses XAF APIs to access an XPClassInfo instance via the XPDictionary property. You can access XPDictionary using only XPO methods as illustrated at [How to get an XPClassInfo instance](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t829506). Also, you can manually create a ReflectionDictionary instance (ReflectionDictionary is an XPDictionary descendant) as described in the [How to create persistent metadata on the fly and load data from an arbitrary table](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/k18482) article.

```
XPDictionary dictionary = new ReflectionDictionary();
XPClassInfo intermediateClassInfo = dictionary.GetClassInfo(typeof(KomutTanim)).FindMember(nameof(KomutTanim.MasterId)).IntermediateClass;
intermediateClassInfo.FindMember("Oid").AddAttribute(new PersistentAttribute("MyName"));

string conn = "My connection string";

IDataStore store = XpoDefault.GetConnectionProvider(conn, AutoCreateOption.SchemaAlreadyExists);

IDataLayer dl = new SimpleDataLayer(dictionary, store);

XpoDefault.DataLayer = dl;
```